# Van't Hoff Equation isolating for K2

Tags: equilibrium

So I wanted to find the theoretical Ka values of acetic acid from 25-65 degrees at 10 degree increments: 25, 35, 45, 55, 65.

[image: Van't Hoff Equation]

I know that the dissociation of acetic acid is endothermic, and when I isolate for K(T2), and [use -1.51kJ/mol as my ∆H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_change_of_solution), i somehow ended up with the following relationship: Ka decreases whilst Temperature increases... thats clearly not normal.
[image: Ka decreases whilst Temperature increases... thats clearly not normal.]

HOWEVER, when I add a negative sign in front of the 1.51, I end up with the following photo: Now this is normal, Ka increases while Temperature increases...
[image: Now this is normal, Ka increases while Temperature increases...3]

Can someone help solve this mystery?? I am probably tunnel-visioning so hard rn... Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: The value -1.51 kJ/mol  is the enthalpy of dissolution, not the enthalpy of dissociation, therefore cannot be used to determine Ka=f(T).

Comment: @Poutnik Ohh, thank you so much! Do you conveniently have the enthalpy of dissociation for acetic acid?

Comment: No, I don't. You have to Google it, or calculate it as the difference of neutralization enthalpies of acetic acid and a strong acid. The former consists formally from dissociation enthalpy and strong acid neutralization enthalpy.

Comment: @Poutnik Oh, Alright! Do you mind explaining it in slightly simpler terms? I am not quite familiar with these new enthalpies you mentioned. Thank you!